# Seeming contradiction regarding resistors and current in circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

How can it be that both of the following are true for a series circuit:

1. If a resistor is replaced with another one of higher resistance, the current in the circuit decreases. If a resistor is added to a circuit, the current in the circuit decreases.
2. The current passing through a $1\Omega$ resistor in the circuit is the same as that passing through a $2\Omega$ resistor in the same circuit.

To me, this is baffling and contradictory. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand how this can be!

Comment: Is (2) a direct quote? Because "a 1 Ohm resistor" and "the 1 Ohm resistor" mean 2 different things (and it looks like they picked the wrong one). Moreover, it uses "the circuit" and "a circuit" to describe the same circuit, which is sloppy editing.

Answer (score 3):

Number 1 says if you add a resister in series to a circuit, the current will drop which is true.  Number 2 says that once you have added the 2 ohm resister to the 1 ohm resister circuit, the current passing though each of the two resisters will be the same, which is also true.  They are not saying the current would be the same as it would be with just the 1 ohm resister, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't understand _why_ the second part is true, given the first part.

Comment: Number 1 has nothing to do with number 2.  All number 2 is saying is that if you have two resisters in series, the current running through each resister will be the same even if the resistances are different.  Number 1 talks about increasing the resistance in a circuit which is different issue.

Comment: @Danny, the current MUST stay within wires and other circuit elements.  Draw a picture of two resistors in series, and note that since individual charges (e.g., electrons) must be conserved, any resistors in series must have the same current flowing through them.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand this!